# Issue while trying to using composite with PATCH with REST API

Tags: composite

I am trying to using REST API with composite and it is failing with this error
"Cannot deserialize instance of  from VALUE_STRING value XXXXXXX or request may be missing a required field"

Without lookup reference, this works fine without any issue.

[image]

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SFSE! Please take a moment to read about [ask] and take the [tour]. It's much easier for everyone involved if you use text instead of posting a screenshot (or, in addition to). Since we can't copy-paste an image as text for testing/tweaking, this results in far more typing for those who try to help.

Answer (score 1):

The object has to be serialized as:

```
"Item__r": {
   "attributes": { "type": "Item_Details__c" },
   "Item_Number__c": 123"
}
```